# Troubleshooting linker loader error on Ubuntu development machine with undefined reference

Tags: c++, jenkins, linker, g++

Have to development systems setup, an Ubuntu machine locally and a Ubuntu Jenkins server.  The project build on local development machine, but when building on Jenkins I get the following error:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -fPIC -o app_bboxd comm_modbus.o bboxes.o -L../lib -lmodbus -lpthread -lrt
comm_modbus.o: In function `COMM_MODBUS__OpenRtu':
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cutom-build/trunk/comm_modbus.c:273: undefined reference to `modbus_rtu_set_rts'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [app_bboxd] Error 1
```

For some reason the linker cannot find the function.  When I use a few built-in command, I can see that the library and function exist:

```
tes@ubuntu:~/workspace/trunk$ grep -rn -i "modbus_rtu_set_rts" /usr/local/include/modbus
/usr/local/include/modbus/modbus-rtu.h:44:MODBUS_API int modbus_rtu_set_rts(modbus_t *ctx, int mode);

test@ubuntu:~/workspace/trunk$ ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep libmodbus
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      919 Jun  8 08:46 libmodbus.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       18 Jun  8 08:46 libmodbus.so -> libmodbus.so.5.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       18 Jun  8 08:46 libmodbus.so.5 -> libmodbus.so.5.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   121972 Jun  8 08:46 libmodbus.so.5.1.0
test@ubuntu:~/workspace/trunk$

test@ubuntu:~/workspace/trunk$ nm /usr/local/lib/libmodbus.so.5.1.0 | grep modbus_rtu_set_rts
00005a70 T modbus_rtu_set_rts
test@ubuntu:~/workspace/trunk$
```

What could be the problem?  How do I figure out why it cannot find this function in the shared object?

Comment: This validation you have performed, are you sure it was in Jenkins env?

Comment: Yes, the output is from development machine, but I have two terminals open and both have exactly the same output.

Comment: Is `libmodbus` library directory in the same location 'local' vs 'server'

Comment: Yes, `pkg-config --modversion --cflags --libs libmodbus` returns the same paths and version.

Comment: I suspect from `-L../lib` . It's a relative path. Are you invoking the compiler from different "working" dirs? Different `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I am invoking from different working paths, but I have also change the directory paths on the local development machine.

Comment: I've tried LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it doesn't work.
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: I found that LIBRARY_PATH works:
`export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib`

Hmm... why would that be?

Comment: Because not all Linux flavours use the same environment vars or paths.

Comment: What I am finding is that `ubuntu@10:~/workspace/thirdparty/libmodbus-3.1.2$ sudo make install` is not actually adding the entry into `ldconfig -v`, so the Jenkins server is missing entry `/usr/local/lib:
 libmodbus.so.5 -> libmodbus.so.5.1.0`

Why would it not be working adding this entry.